# JQuery Slice AddClass

Tags: jquery, addclass, slice

I have a piece of code that works to add a class to menu items:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submenu ul li ul li').addClass("top4");
});
```

This works fine. However I just want to apply the class to the first 4 of each block of menu items.

I assumed that I could use [`slice`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
.slice(0,3)
```

However the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submenu ul li ul li').slice(0,3).addClass("top4");
});
```

doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [:lt-selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) as below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submenu ul li ul').find('li:lt(4)').addClass("top4");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GQN6F/)

Comment: Deleted my answer since it basically completely wrong! +1 to you :)

Comment: @andrew see how slice can be used in the given scenario - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GQN6F/3/

Comment: any ideas why my original didn't work? I can't see any reason why not

Comment: here is a fiddle by @ArunPJohny of your original code http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GQN6F/2

Comment: @user2524219 because `$('#submenu ul li ul li')` will return all the `li` elements so when you say `slice(0, 4)` it will return the first 4 items from the entire list instead of 4 from each menu

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[:lt()](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)** selector instead:

> Select all elements at an index less than index within the matched
>   set.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submenu ul li ul').find('li:lt(4)').addClass("top4");
});
```